# Split list of tuples based on value within tuple

Tags: python

If I have the following:

```
[(1,2),(2,3),(0,0),(4,0),(0,1),(3,9),(2,0),(2,4)]
```

How can I split it into:

```
[(1,2),(2,3)], [(0,1),(3,9)], [(2,4),]
```

were every time I see a tuple with a 0 at index 1, e.g. (1,0), I split the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import groupby

x = [(1,2), (2,3), (0,0), (4,0), (0,1), (3,9), (2,0), (2,4)]

print [l for l in [list(group) for key, group in groupby(x, key=lambda k: k[1]==0)]
             if l[0][1] != 0]

[OUT] [[(1,2), (2,3)], [(0,1), (3,9)], [(2,4)]]
```

It produces a list that you can iterate over to get those sublists.

Comment: Here's a version that's slightly more efficient, since it filters on `k`: `[list(group) for key, group in groupby(x, key=lambda t: t[1] != 0) if key]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly slick, but you could just loop over it like this:

```
myList = [(1,2),(2,3),(0,0),(4,0),(0,1),(3,9),(2,0),(2,4)]
groupedList = []
subList = []
for tup in myList:
    if tup[1] == 0:
        if subList != []:
            groupedList.append(subList)
            subList = []
    else:
        subList.append(tup)
if subList != []:
    groupedList.append(subList)
print groupedList
```

Output:

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(0, 1), (3, 9)], [(2, 4)]]
```